# How to compare a vector of const char[]

Tags: c++, vector, compare

I have a vector that is composed of const char[] and I want to be able to check if each character array is equal to the rest in the vector. So if this is how I initialize, and then I assign a random const char[] to 5 parts of the vector array, how can I compare them without using ==?

```
const char sled[]="sled";
const char car[]="car";
const char house[]="house";
const char dog[] ="dog";
vector<const char[]> vect;


    if (vect[0]== vect[1]== vect[2]. == vect[3] == vect[4])
    {
    cout << "They are all equal!"
        return;
    }
```

Comment: maybe `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Why the limitation on the use of `==`?

Comment: The statement `if (vect[0]== vect[1]== vect[2] == vect[3] == vect[4])` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 5):

`const char *` or C-strings must be compared with [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). You can write your own `for loop` that compares the `chars` one by one as well.

Comment: `bool streq(char const* lhs, char const* rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs) == 0; }` :)

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt to use C-style strings with `std::vector` [won't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/258157cd6145c750), but assuming you find a way to make it work, here's how I would compare two strings, making sure that no operator `==` is ever used (considering that `strcmp` might make use of that operator in its implementation):

```
bool eq(char a, char b) {
    return !(static_cast<int>(a) - static_cast<int>(b));
}

bool are_equal(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; !eq(a[i], '\0'); ++i)
        if  (!eq(a[i], b[i]))
            return false;
    return (eq(b[i], '\0'));
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58ef8a75ccc6925b)'s a live example of it's execution. Now, if you wish to actually make things the right way, here's how you would do it:

```
std::vector<std::string> vect;
vect.emplace_back("sled");
vect.emplace_back("car");
vect.emplace_back("house");
vect.emplace_back("dog");

if (std::all_of(
    vect.begin() + 1,
    vect.end(),
    [&](const std::string& s) {
        return s == vect.front();
    }
)) {
    std::cout << "They are all equal!";
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da8aa9f458ef561c)'s a live example of that too.

Have a nice coding day.